# Python nosetest ValueError exception

Tags: python, testing, nosetests

I have some function:

```
def reverse_number(num):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except ValueError:
        return "Please provide number"
```

and test for this:

```
assert_raises(ValueError, reverse.reverse_number, "error")
```

But when I call `nosetests` I got this error:

```
AssertionError: ValueError not raised
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `reverse_number` catches the exception, preveting the exception to be raised; cause the assertion failure because `assert_raises` call expects the function call raises the `ValueError` exception.

Simply not catching the exception, you can get what you want:

```
def reverse_number(num):
    return int(num)
```

Or, you can catch the exception, do something, and re-raise the exception using `raise` statement:

```
def reverse_number(num):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except ValueError:
        # do something
        raise  # <--- re-raise the exception
```